Has anyone estimated Super-heavy's return flight telemetry during IFT3 while assuming that its center engines all relit on schedule?
By telemetry, I mean a chart of altitude, speed, remaining propellant, and possibly dynamic pressure, versus time.

Flightclub.io is the first thing that comes to mind though I think there's either a membershipwall or paywall that have stopped me from using it in practice. Not sure if it'll actually be useful, sorry--but it might be

@ErinAnne Thanks! Will check it out.

flightclub.io is what I'll recommend.

Just a nit - but I would call what you are looking for is the "state".  Telemetry, by definition is "measurement at a distance" which in the industry means information broadcast from the vehicle.
